# WPF: Label doesn't show up in code behind

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, code-behind

Ok, so I've been looking all over for a anwser, but I starting to wonder if I would even know it if I saw it. I'm new to WPF, but have been doing Windows Forms in C# for a few years now.

My Question is: **Why can't I access a label from the code behind that I "dragged-n-dropped" on to the grid and renamed?**

XML CODE:

```
<Window x:Class="IMCommand.NewProblemWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="New Problem" Height="800" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="Initial Detection and Recording" Height="168" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,45,0,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="754" FontSize="15">
            <Grid>
                <Label Content="Application/Server" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,11,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="324" Background="#FFCBCBCB"></TextBox>

                <Label Content="AE Problem Ticket #" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,52,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox Background="#FFCBCBCB" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,54,0,0" Name="BOX_AEProblem" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" />

                <Label Content="Start Time" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,86,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" />
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,91,0,0" Name="BOX_StartTime" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118" IsReadOnly="True" />

                <Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="221,89,0,0" Name="LBL_StartTimeConvert" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Classification and Initial Support" Height="333" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,260,0,0" Name="groupBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="754" FontSize="15">
            <Grid>
                <Label Content="Description" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,96,0,0" Name="LBL_Description" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <RichTextBox Height="137" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,96,0,0" Name="richTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="590" Background="#FFCBCBCB" Cursor="IBeam" ToolTip="Describe the problem..." VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" FontSize="12" BorderBrush="#FF151414" />
                <RichTextBox Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,44,0,0" Name="richTextBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="590" Background="#FFCBCBCB" />
                <Label Content="Summary" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,44,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The particular label I'm refereing to is the last label in the first GroupBox named "LBL_StartTimeConvert"

```
<Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="221,89,0,0" Name="LBL_StartTimeConvert" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" />
```

When I go into the Code behind file, I am unable to get "LBL_StartTimeConvert" to show up in intellisense. How do I access this label from the C# code? I need to change the labels text. Thanks!

PS>> Any good resources/books that you can point me to on learning WPF (like WPF 101 or WPF for Dummies) would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does your project compile when you use LBL_StartTimeConvert in code behind file? I suppose it is only a problem with IntelliSense.

Comment: No, if I try to manually type in the name, it instantly throws a error.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. In what method are you trying to access LBL_StartTimeConvert? Can you add the code behind file and an example where you expect LBL_StartTimeConvert to be accessible?

Comment: I just pasted your information into vs2010 and I am able to see LBL_StartTimeConvert in intellisense. In what method are you specifically trying to access it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please make sure your namespace and window name is same in code behind as xaml file cause when I have pasted your code in my sample window, it working fine and also I can access label LBL_StartTimeConvert.

Please create new sample WPF project and put your code which is inside `<grid>` tag and then check it.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. A restart of VS solved it.
Sometimes it really is a bug ;)

Comment: Worked here too !

Comment: this really should have been the accepted answer.  After checking and rechecking, finally I restarted VS and all is well.

Answer (score 3):

You should use x:Name instead of Name
"x:Name: Specifies a run-time object name for the instance that exists in run-time code after an object element is processed. In general, you will frequently use a WPF-defined equivalent property for x:Name. Such properties map specifically to a CLR backing property and are thus more convenient for application programming, where you frequently use run time code to find the named elements from initialized XAML."
**See XAML overview [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx)**

Comment: x:Name and Name are synonymous in this context since it is what is referred to above as the "WPF-defined equivalent property for x:Name".